# Klipper BED_SCREWS_ADJUST and SKEW_PROFILE interaction

Tags: calibration, klipper

Klipper lets you define a skew profile that is loaded / unloaded on demand during START_PRINT / END_PRINT macros called during printing of a sliced file. This seems to be the recommended way to apply the skew in Klipper, in fact it is in the documentation this way: https://www.klipper3d.org/skew_correction.html.

My question is, should I also manually load the skew profile prior to executing the BED_SCREWS_ADJUST built-in command in Klipper?

Or does BED_SCREWS_ADJUST ignore the skew entirely so it doesn't matter?

Comment: This is not dependant on the printer, it's Klipper/Firmware.

Comment: My question is about Klipper, it is true. :)

Answer (score 1):

The skew correction works in X/Y axis while bed screws helps you correct the ax axis. Since they don’t work in the same axis, I don’t see why they would interfere with each other.

Comment: Welcome and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [Tour](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Comment: @victor-lazaro But skew correction I am doing has XY, XZ, YZ component - https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:2972743. I thought this meant Z coordinate is adjusted, similar to a mesh. But I could be wrong! Still a bit unclear about it.

Comment: You’re right. My bad. I don’t use skew correction on mine, I just fixed the frame.

Comment: After some months with the printer, I think I agree that squaring the frame of my little cartesian printer is simple enough to avoid skew correction in software as well.